# Full Load in Redshift - DROP vs TRUNCATE

Tags: amazon-redshift, truncate, vacuum

As part of daily load in Redshift, I have a couple of tables to drop and full load all of them, (data size is small, less than 1 million).

My question is which of the below two strategies is better in terms of CPU utilization and memory in Redshift:
1) Truncate data
2) DROP and Recreate Table.

If I truncate tables, should I perform Vacuum on tables every day as I have read that frequent drop and recreate tables in the database cause fragmentation of pages.

And one of the tables I would like to enable compression. So, is there any downside creating DDL with encoding every day.

Please advise! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drop the tables you will lose assigned permissions to these tables. If you have views for these tables they will be obsolete.

Truncate is a better option, truncate does not require vacuum or analyze, it is built for use cases like this.

For further info [Redshift Truncate documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi8kpTVi4PjAhVRG80KHYgnBWIQFjABegQIChAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.aws.amazon.com%2Fredshift%2Flatest%2Fdg%2Fr_TRUNCATE.html&usg=AOvVaw0y8mi4pI66UU9tNhAw1xr1)